# Filtrar um array dentro de outro array(Ionic)

Tags: javascript, ionic

Olá comecei a estudar Ionic a pouco tempo e estou com o seguinte problema.
Tenho o seguinte ARRAY:

```
"ordserv": [
    {
        "codemp": "01",
        "numos": "0000000001",
        "codcli": "000001",
        "datcadast": "2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "user_id": "INFTEC",
        "staos": "7",
        "descricao": "Teste",
        "codtabpreco": null,
        "codcpagto": null,
        "subgrupo": null,
        "resptecnico": null,
        "cli_respfinanc": null,
        "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "datresposta": null,
        "resp_resposta": null,
        "numpedcli": null,
        "resesperado": null,
        "avaliacaofinal": null,
        "razsoccli": "EMPRESA USUÁRIA DO SISTEMA",
        "numcgccpfcli": "00000000000000",
        "descpagto": null,
        "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
        "Equipamento": [
            {
                "codemp": "01",
                "numos": "0000000001",
                "numequip": "001",
                "seriequip": "SER-A001",
                "codmat": "0121000003",
                "numnf": null,
                "sernf": null,
                "codforn": null,
                "numitemnf": null,
                "desmat": "CEO GP4 24 FO PARA INSTALACAO AEREA",
                "razsocforn": null,
                "numcgccpf": null
            }
        ],        
    {
        "codemp": "01",
        "numos": "0000000002",
        "codcli": "000002",
        "datcadast": "2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "user_id": "INFTEC",
        "staos": "1",
        "descricao": "Teste 2",
        "codtabpreco": null,
        "codcpagto": null,
        "subgrupo": null,
        "resptecnico": null,
        "cli_respfinanc": null,
        "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "datresposta": null,
        "resp_resposta": null,
        "numpedcli": null,
        "resesperado": null,
        "avaliacaofinal": null,
        "razsoccli": "VIANET TELECOMUNICACOES E INTERNET LTDA",
        "numcgccpfcli": "05884946000181",
        "descpagto": null,
        "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
        "Equipamento": [
            {
                "codemp": "01",
                "numos": "0000000002",
                "numequip": "001",
                "seriequip": "SER-A002",
                "codmat": 0121000002,
                "numnf": null,
                "sernf": null,
                "codforn": null,
                "numitemnf": null,
                "desmat": null,
                "razsocforn": null,
                "numcgccpf": null
            }
        ],
    {
        "codemp": "01",
        "numos": "0000000003",
        "codcli": "000001",
        "datcadast": "2020-05-21T14:50:06.987Z",
        "user_id": "INFTEC",
        "staos": "3",
        "descricao": "Teste",
        "codtabpreco": null,
        "codcpagto": null,
        "subgrupo": null,
        "resptecnico": null,
        "cli_respfinanc": null,
        "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "datresposta": null,
        "resp_resposta": null,
        "numpedcli": null,
        "resesperado": null,
        "avaliacaofinal": null,
        "razsoccli": "EMPRESA USUÁRIA DO SISTEMA",
        "numcgccpfcli": "00000000000000",
        "descpagto": null,
        "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
        "Equipamento": [
            {
                "codemp": "01",
                "numos": "0000000003",
                "numequip": "001",
                "seriequip": "SER-A001",
                "codmat": "0121000001",
                "numnf": null,
                "sernf": null,
                "codforn": null,
                "numitemnf": null,
                "desmat": "CEO GP4 24 FO PARA INSTALACAO AEREA",
                "razsocforn": null,
                "numcgccpf": null
            }
        ],           

    }
]
```

Estou tentando filtrar as ordserv que tenham no Equipamento o codmat que eu inseri no sistema. O retorno eu queria outro array mas só com os ordserv filtrados.

Tentei o seguine código que andei pesquisando  mas não obtive sucesso:

```
this.ordserv = this.ordserv.filter((f) => f.Equipamento.find(j => j.codmat == this.codmat))
```

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, como precisa pesquisar um array dentro de um array, precisa fazer um outro filter para pesquisar em "Equipamentos", mas nesse caso, que tenha "algum" equipamento com o codmat desejado, então podemos usar `some` no lugar de filter. Veja esse exmeplo:

```js
var obj = {
  "ordserv": [
    {
      "codemp": "01",
      "numos": "0000000001",
      "codcli": "000001",
      "datcadast": "2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
      "user_id": "INFTEC",
      "staos": "7",
      "descricao": "Teste",
      "codtabpreco": null,
      "codcpagto": null,
      "subgrupo": null,
      "resptecnico": null,
      "cli_respfinanc": null,
      "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
      "datresposta": null,
      "resp_resposta": null,
      "numpedcli": null,
      "resesperado": null,
      "avaliacaofinal": null,
      "razsoccli": "EMPRESA USUÁRIA DO SISTEMA",
      "numcgccpfcli": "00000000000000",
      "descpagto": null,
      "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
      "Equipamento": [
        {
          "codemp": "01",
          "numos": "0000000001",
          "numequip": "001",
          "seriequip": "SER-A001",
          "codmat": "0121000003",
          "numnf": null,
          "sernf": null,
          "codforn": null,
          "numitemnf": null,
          "desmat": "CEO GP4 24 FO PARA INSTALACAO AEREA",
          "razsocforn": null,
          "numcgccpf": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "codemp": "01",
      "numos": "0000000002",
      "codcli": "000002",
      "datcadast": "2020-05-19T00:00:00.000Z",
      "user_id": "INFTEC",
      "staos": "1",
      "descricao": "Teste 2",
      "codtabpreco": null,
      "codcpagto": null,
      "subgrupo": null,
      "resptecnico": null,
      "cli_respfinanc": null,
      "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
      "datresposta": null,
      "resp_resposta": null,
      "numpedcli": null,
      "resesperado": null,
      "avaliacaofinal": null,
      "razsoccli": "VIANET TELECOMUNICACOES E INTERNET LTDA",
      "numcgccpfcli": "05884946000181",
      "descpagto": null,
      "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
      "Equipamento": [
        {
          "codemp": "01",
          "numos": "0000000002",
          "numequip": "001",
          "seriequip": "SER-A002",
          "codmat": "0121000002",
          "numnf": null,
          "sernf": null,
          "codforn": null,
          "numitemnf": null,
          "desmat": null,
          "razsocforn": null,
          "numcgccpf": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "codemp": "01",
      "numos": "0000000003",
      "codcli": "000001",
      "datcadast": "2020-05-21T14:50:06.987Z",
      "user_id": "INFTEC",
      "staos": "3",
      "descricao": "Teste",
      "codtabpreco": null,
      "codcpagto": null,
      "subgrupo": null,
      "resptecnico": null,
      "cli_respfinanc": null,
      "datprometida": "2020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
      "datresposta": null,
      "resp_resposta": null,
      "numpedcli": null,
      "resesperado": null,
      "avaliacaofinal": null,
      "razsoccli": "EMPRESA USUÁRIA DO SISTEMA",
      "numcgccpfcli": "00000000000000",
      "descpagto": null,
      "razsoccli_respfinanc": null,
      "Equipamento": [
        {
          "codemp": "01",
          "numos": "0000000003",
          "numequip": "001",
          "seriequip": "SER-A001",
          "codmat": "0121000001",
          "numnf": null,
          "sernf": null,
          "codforn": null,
          "numitemnf": null,
          "desmat": "CEO GP4 24 FO PARA INSTALACAO AEREA",
          "razsocforn": null,
          "numcgccpf": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var codmatFiltro = "0121000003";

var objFiltrado = obj.ordserv.filter(function(o) {
   return o.Equipamento.some(function(e){
     return e.codmat == codmatFiltro;
   });
});
   
console.log(objFiltrado);
```

Aqui a documentação do `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some